# How to automatically back up local MySQL database to a remote MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a local instance of a mysql database and a remote mysql database.

I want to back up the localhost server to the remote server automatically every night.

My applications will be running from the localhost, but management also wants the data to be housed by our IT company.

I believe they want the servers to be fail safe, because if one of the servers are down they still want to be able to perform their daily task like normal.

Edit: After more research I believe a Master-Master replication will make the servers fail-safe.

Comment: Maybe replication is more suitable solution?

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers)!  :-) p.s. welcome to the forum, but your question is a bit unspecific and vague. What's stopping you using `mysqldump` and having the backup SFTP'd to your provider? Something like [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/files/)?

Comment: @Vérace this tool, will it store mysql dumps into the remote server?

Comment: Not sure - but even after it backs up locally, you could FTP the file?

Comment: @Vérace hmm i see, I did some more research, I think a Master-Master replication is what is more ideal for this situation. I believe my management is looking for more of a fail safe system

Comment: Hmm... and have them backup the replica off-site? Seems a rather expensive strategy? I suppose it all depends on stuff like [this](https://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Defining-RTO-MTBF-and-MTTR). I thought [this](https://medium.com/auto-backup-mysql-to-google-drive/auto-backup-mysql-to-google-drive-c8b2178b097e) was interesting? You can use XtraBackup for hot backups. You could also have a VM in the cloud? Again, for failsafe-ness, every extra 9 is gonna cost you a 0! :-)

Comment: No I don't think they will have to do anything, the only thing they are doing is hosting a remote virtual machine on their data center(which i have access to), we also have a local machine. We recently migrated from our local machine to their remote server, to be more "secure,safe". But their data center crashed yesterday, so now management wants me to use the local machine to run application, and backup daily to the remote server. So an ideal situation would be, if the localhost crashed application will access remote server for both read and write. @Vérace

Comment: @Vérace I also like that second link you showed me, it seems like a easier solution to M-M

Comment: `so now management wants me to use the local machine to run application`- and suppose your premises burns down? :-) Or the local machine crashes? To be  truly secure, you want offsite Multi-Master Replication in 3 or 5 different data centres! Mucho dinero! Is your priority data loss or uptime?